# My chiffon cake have lots of holes

Tags: baking

This keeps happening to my chiffon cakes. Sometimes it comes out perfect, sometimes this happens. Desperate for help!

Comment: Welcome! Can you perhaps add a bit more info - especially your recipe and method - to give our readers more to work with? The [tour] and the [help], especially [ask] should help.